# 555 timer control voltage

Tags: pwm, 555

I'm trying connect the 555 timer as a pulse wave modulator. Notice from the diagram below, the - input of Comp1 is internally connected to \$2/3V_{CC}\$. The control voltage is applied at pin 5. The question is how can you apply a varying voltage to a point that is already set to a particular voltage. Doesn't that result in a short ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't quite have it right.  Pin 5 is not SET at Vcc*2/3.  It is connected to a voltage divider that outputs Vcc*2/3 when there is no other connection.  When connected to a voltage source, the currents through all the 5K resistors will change such that pin 5 is now tied at Vcontrol

Answer (score 1):

No. Pin 5 is connected to one of the junctions in a string of three 5K resistors (and the input of a comparator).

As long as your external voltage source has an impedance that is significantly lower than about (5k || (5k + 5k)) or about 3.33K, you will be able to drive the voltage to whatever you want.